# How to extend MemberExpression using another expression

Tags: c#, expression

Given

```
Expression<Func<SubType, PropertyType>> selector = subType => subtype.[...].Property
```

I want to extend another MemberExpression which provide SubType like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ParentType), "parameter");
var subTypeProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(ParentType.SubType));
```

To produce another MemberExpression which starts from ParentType, traverse same path as first selector expression and provides an MemberExpression like:

```
parentType.SubType.[...].Property
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434133/593630) link provide good explanation and solution for my question

using ExpressionVisitor you can traverse first selector, looking for parameter expressions  and replace all parameter expressions with "subTypeProperty" MemberExpession

using:

```
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

then:

```
var newSelector = new ReplaceVisitor(selector.Parameters.First(), subTypeProperty)
            .Visit(selector.Body);
```