# "The LINQ expression could not be translated" when accessing the value of the property of an entity dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am writing a class to access an Entity framework DbSet.

I am having troubles with a FetchMany method.

I am using inheritance and I need to get the value of the Identifier of the table by using a method, as each class has a different Identifier name and need to access in a generic way.

I have read several threads about this error message, but I haven't been able to find any with something similar to this issue, having to access a property of the entity dynamically.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class Test {
    public DbSet<MyClass> DbSet => GetDbSet(Context);

    protected Expression<Func<MyClass, string>> GetIdExpression() =>
        return entity => entity.Id;
        
    protected Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> CheckIds(List<string> ids) {
        var idExpression = GetIdExpression();
        return entity => ids.Contains(idExpression.Compile()(entity));
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> FetchMany(List<string> ids) {
        var query = DbSet.Where(CheckIds(ids));
        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
List<MyClass> entities = Test.FetchMany(ids).ToList();
```

I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression  could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TestApi.Test.FetchMany(List`1 ids)
   at TestApi.Controllers.MyController.FetchManyTest(List`1 ids)
   at lambda_method143(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought that using a method returning an expresion like the `GetIdExpression()` method in the example would fix the problem.

Maybe it is related to my Entity framework version?
I am using Entity framework core 5.0.7

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**:
Thank you all for your help.

Finally I have managed to achieve it by modifying the `CheckIds()` method using code from the link suggested as duplicate:
[Combine two Linq lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433316/combine-two-linq-lambda-expressions)

The code of the method now is:

```
protected Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> CheckIds(List<string> ids) {
    Expression<Func<string, bool>> mainExpression = id => ids.Contains(id);
    Expression<Func<MyClass, string>> idExpression = GetIdExpression();

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "param");
    InvocationExpression body = Expression.Invoke(mainExpression, Expression.Invoke(idExpression, param));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are IDs in database strings or numbers

Comment: You have to use `LINQKit`. It can transform `Compile()` to translatable Expression Tree. With pure EF Core it is not possible.