# How to break a .Where() with OR operator into separated function calls?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm have a query with some "OR" operators. for instance.

```
entities.Where(e=> (...) || (...) || (...) || (...));
```

I would like to break this into several calls like the `Where()` function allows me. for instance:

```
entities = entities.Where(e => (some logic A));
// ...
entities = entities.Where(e => (some logic B));
// ...
entities = entities.Where(e => (some logic C));
```

Is possible to do the same but for a `OR` logic instead of `AND` Logic?

The main reason that I would like to break this logic into several lines of code is that each `OR` can be applied by different functions.

Comment: consider the expression syntax.

Comment: @DanielA.White ?

Comment: To learn more about using expressions to do this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/9683474/8155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
set1 = entities.Where(e => (some logic A));
set2 = entities.Where(e => (some logic B));
set3 = entities.Where(e => (some logic C));

entities = set1.Union(set2).Union(set3);
```

Comment: wouldn't that be like 3 separated queries ?

Comment: In LinqToObjects - yes, 3 enumerations of the source.
In most other query providers - no, it would be a single union'd query.  It's important to know that queries are not executed until enumerated (as happens in foreach or ToList)

Comment: is this a most expensive query than regular "OR" in EntityFramework (SQL Server) ?

Comment: @DanielSantos - Profile it and find out. It's the only way to know.

Comment: Depending on the underlying implementation, you might also need a `Distinct` call to avoid duplicates where one item matches multiple criteria.

Comment: No, there wouldn't be three separated queries. In fact, the code described only creates an IQueryable object. The IQueriable.Expression changes with each LINQ function, but no query is performed yet, The query is performed as soon as you really start enumerating. This is usually done by functions like ToList(), ToArray(), FirstOrDefault(), Max(), ... At that moment the IQueryable.Provider interprets the one and only IQueryable.Expression, which will lead to one database query (depending on the quality of the IQueryable.Provider).

Comment: @jmcilhinney: No; `.Union()` (unlike `.Concat()`) already does that.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks. I see that the documentation says that so I should have looked first.